# Headless Selenium is not extracting data in Python using Chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium

While navigating to the page, It is able to extract the data.

**Code:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options1 = Options()
options1.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() +"/chromedriver",options = options1)
this is how I am getting the chrome driver
```

`content = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")`
this is how I am getting the content from the navigated page. While we are navigating to the page able to extract the data.

Comment: you have declared your options variable as `options1` but youre passing `options` inside the `Chrome`. Fix that, first of all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like below?

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.getcwd() +"/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: I tried your way, when I am trying with headless that time It is asking for captcha from one website. and without headless proper things able to get data